# How to make single row collection view cell with dynamic button width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

Guys I'm working on a project and I want to make a navigation bar like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfG3B.png)
here I knows there navigation bar is transparent and below navigation bar there must be a collectionview or scrollview I want to know how to make this design with collectionview or scrollview because I tried alot but maybe I didn't much know about collectionview flowlayout and and which one way is better(collectionview or scrollview).

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to embed the collectionView or scrollView inside your navigation bar? Also, how many buttons do you want to add in?

Comment: I can use collectionview and number of buttons should be dynamic and width of button also dynamic according to the content

Comment: Have you looked at this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html